# Overriding of values in Json object

Tags: java, json

I am trying to generate key value pair JSON format, but it gets overwritten, Could anyone help me please

### Program

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
List<JSONObject> json = new ArrayList<>();
ListIterator l = desc.listIterator();// desc is an arraylist and has some values
ListIterator l2 = amts.listIterator();//amts ia an arraylist and has some values

while (l.hasNext() && l2.hasNext()) {
    jobj.put("Des", l.next());
    jobj.put("Amount", l2.next());
    json.add(jobj);//trying to add json to combine two object into single object
    System.out.println("Datas of jsons" + json);//values are overriding
}
```

### Expected output:

```
[
 {"Des":"Mani","Amount":846},
 {"Des":"Shiva","Amount":900},
 {"Des":"Sam","Amount":23}, 
 {"Des":"Rajashree","Amount":923},
 {"Des":"Kokila","Amount":86}, 
 {"Des":"Samantha","Amount":12}
]
```

### **Output I am getting**

```
[
 {"Des":"Mani","Amount":846}, 
 {"Des":"Mani","Amount":846}, 
 {"Des":"Mani","Amount":846}, 
 {"Des":"Mani","Amount":846}, 
 {"Des":"Mani","Amount":846}, 
 {"Des":"Mani","Amount":846}
]
```

I am new to java if it is a silly question plz don't block me

Comment: Put `JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();` into while-loop.

Comment: Your JSONObject is getting overridden due to the fact that you declare the jsonobject outside the loop. Just instantiate jsonobject ‘jobj’ inside the while loop and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your JSONObject initialization from outside of while loop to inside of it. As shown below

```
while(l.hasNext() && l2.hasNext()){
  JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
  jobj.put("Des",l.next());
  jobj.put("Amount",l2.next());
  json.add(jobj);//trying to add json to combine two object into single object
  System.out.println("Datas of jsons"+json);//values are overriding
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, but my I know what is happening behind the scenes?, what happens when I declare Jsonobject inside the while loop?. Does it create another reference inside heap memory?

Comment: Yes you are right. When JSONobject is declared inside loop , a new reference is created for each loop iteration